# "$-" Returns 569X During ZSH Invocation

Tags: zsh, options

### Background

While studying the shell parameter, `$-`, for `sh`, `bash`, and `zsh`, I discovered that it returned current option flags, **hBc**, for both `sh` and `bash` but **569X** for `zsh`.

```
SUSE >> bash -c 'echo "$0"; echo "$-"'
bash
hBc
```

```
SUSE >> sh -c 'echo "$0"; echo "$-"'
sh
hBc
```

```
SUSE >> zsh -c 'echo "$0"; echo "$-"'
zsh
569X
```

---

### Issue

I used `man zsh` to find information about **569X** but found nothing. Could someone explain why "$-" is returning **569X** for `zsh`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$-` can be understood by looking up the single-character options corresponding to each character:

- `-5` causes Zsh to report the status of background jobs immediately;
- `-6` causes Zsh to run all background jobs at a lower priority;
- `-9` causes Zsh to automatically list choices when a completion is ambiguous;
- `-X` causes Zsh to show the type of files when listing files for completion.

See [the description of options](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#Description-of-Options) in the Zsh manual. The four options above are the four non-initialisation options enabled by default which can be controlled with a single-character option.